# Jquery function after Ajax submit not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Here is my situation, It's giving me lot of trouble..

I have an ajax submit form, on submit, id like an action to happen.

I'm quite dependant as this is on squarespace, so i dont have acess to much code.

On submit of the form ( when sucessfull), I can see a 'hidden' class is added.

So i would like to use this for my action as:

```
if ( $("input.button").hasClass("hidden") ) {

  $("#block-yui_3_17_2_2_1515660345355_6688").fadeIn();
        };
```

But nothing seems to happen !! event alert is not working as well, I believe this is due because its not reloading the page as the hidden class appear only when the form has been submitted.

Is there any other method which could work to achieve this ?

Thanks a lot for your help, it will be a life saving  !!!

--update --

BElow the all form html:

```
<form autocomplete="on" action="https://website.squarespace.com" method="POST" onsubmit="
  return (function(form) {
    Y.use('squarespace-form-submit', 'node', function(Y){
      (new Y.Squarespace.FormSubmit({
        formNode: Y.Node(form)
      })).submit('5a568ac053450ad102451bc4', '5a568a42c8302558efde1ae7', 'page-5a568a42c8302558efde1ae7');
    });
    return false;
  })(this)" data-form-id="5a568ac053450ad102451bc4">

<div class="field-list clear">

    <div id="text-yui_3_17_2_1_1515620880734_20061" class="form-item field text required">
        <label class="title" for="text-yui_3_17_2_1_1515620880734_20061-field">FULL NAME
            <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>

        <input class="field-element text" type="text" id="text-yui_3_17_2_1_1515620880734_20061-field">
    </div>

    <div id="email-yui_3_17_2_3_1515620880734_11301" class="form-item field email required">
        <label class="title" for="email-yui_3_17_2_3_1515620880734_11301-field">E-MAIL ADDRESS
            <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>

        <input class="field-element" name="email" x-autocompletetype="email" type="text" spellcheck="false" id="email-yui_3_17_2_3_1515620880734_11301-field">
    </div>

    <div id="radio-yui_3_17_2_1_1515620880734_21108" class="form-item field radio required">
        <div class="title" for="radio-yui_3_17_2_1_1515620880734_21108-field">GENDER
            <span class="required">*</span>
        </div>


        <div class="option">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-yui_3_17_2_1_1515620880734_21108-field" value="MALE">
                <div id="check"></div> MALE</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-yui_3_17_2_1_1515620880734_21108-field" value="FEMALE">
                <div id="check"></div> FEMALE</label>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="radio-yui_3_17_2_1_1515620880734_21855" class="form-item field radio required">
        <div class="title" for="radio-yui_3_17_2_1_1515620880734_21855-field">SHOE SIZE (EU SIZE)
            <span class="required">*</span>
        </div>


        <div class="option">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-yui_3_17_2_1_1515620880734_21855-field" value="36">
                <div id="check"></div> 36</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-yui_3_17_2_1_1515620880734_21855-field" value="37">
                <div id="check"></div> 37</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-yui_3_17_2_1_1515620880734_21855-field" value="38">
                <div id="check"></div> 38</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-yui_3_17_2_1_1515620880734_21855-field" value="39">
                <div id="check"></div> 39</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-yui_3_17_2_1_1515620880734_21855-field" value="40">
                <div id="check"></div> 40</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-yui_3_17_2_1_1515620880734_21855-field" value="41">
                <div id="check"></div> 41</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-yui_3_17_2_1_1515620880734_21855-field" value="42">
                <div id="check"></div> 42</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-yui_3_17_2_1_1515620880734_21855-field" value="43">
                <div id="check"></div> 43</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-yui_3_17_2_1_1515620880734_21855-field" value="44">
                <div id="check"></div> 44</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-yui_3_17_2_1_1515620880734_21855-field" value="45">
                <div id="check"></div> 45</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-yui_3_17_2_1_1515620880734_21855-field" value="46">
                <div id="check"></div> 46</label>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="form-button-wrapper form-button-wrapper--align-center">
    <input class="button sqs-system-button sqs-editable-button" type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>


<div class="hidden form-submission-text">Thank you!</div>

<div class="hidden form-submission-html" data-submission-html=""></div>
```

Comment: We need to see more of your code, specifically what event you're attaching to to send the AJAX request. Assuming this is within a `form` element it sounds likely that the form is being submit before your AJAX request has a chance to complete and is in turn causing a page redirection

Comment: Hi Rory,

Thanks for your fast reply, I have attach the html fo the form, unortunately i dont have access to anything else. Im looking for a way to make it happen on the current page and not a new one / redirection . . . Is there any way to make this work in your thought ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right, you want a block to appear with a fade-in once the form is submitted.

A few things here:

First, attaching to an arbitrary class change to make something happen feels very fragile. Why not try attaching this action to the form submit event?

Second, the javascript you put as an example will never make it unless the button was hidden on page load. You would need to attach this code to an actual dom event to execute it.

Here is my proposed solution. Note that this solution assumes the block with the ID you provide is already mounted on the DOM:

Since you seem to want to listen for a submit event and then make something appear, and your code was generic enough, you could:

```
$('form').onSubmit(function() {
   $("#block-yui_3_17_2_2_1515660345355_6688").fadeIn();
});
```

There are simpler css transitions as well, again assuming the block is already on the DOM when the page loads.

Only final gotcha might be that you don't have jquery loaded on your site. I recommend adding jQuery from a Google CDN.